# Create photoswipe on UL>LI>FIGURE markup

Tags: photoswipe

On photoswipe docs the markup is **div/figure/img**. But i want other markup.

How to **"Creating an Array of Slide Objects"** for this **ul/li/figure/img** markup. I know i need somehow to edit the "var initPhotoSwipeFromDOM = function(gallerySelector) {" function. But do not now what the changes i need to do?

This is my markup:

```
<ul class="my-gallery" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/ImageGallery">
<li>
    <figure>
        <a href="large-image.jpg" data-size="600x400">
            <img src="small-image.jpg" itemprop="thumbnail"/>
        </a>
        <figcaption itemprop="caption description">Image caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</li>

</ul>
```

Related Q i so on the internet:
https://codedump.io/share/Hc9do6CIJgwH/1/how-do-i-get-photoswipe-to-recognize-entire-gallery-from-list-of-thumbnail-images

Answer (score 1):

You must correctly travers the DOM and pass proper elements, I am not able to explain it, it's just about understanding how and which nodes are selected - here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/TMMC/6ec51c46d9fa57e1fd6a480f0d5da86d - I had the same issue, exactly the same code. Look for comments starting with `make it works with`.

Comment: sorry to report that this gist didn't work for me^^
this link here did work, however: https://gist.github.com/onizuka17/efff70f10b1af55c6c5fe661a034878d
(of course, just the photoswipe part)

Comment: @mtness This is different markup - without `figure` element in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Try `".my-gallery > li > figure > a"` as `gallerySelector`

Comment: I also have a tiny jQuery plugin for photoswipe. Supports any html format like yours, including fancybox and does not requires image dimensions to be defined. https://ergec.github.io/jQuery-for-PhotoSwipe/